# Combining oscillatory integrals of the first and second kind

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, asymptotics, schwartz-distributions

Consider an oscillatory integral of the first kind
$$
I_\lambda(x)=\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e^{i\lambda\Phi(x,y)}a(x,y)\,d y,\quad \lambda\geq 0,\; a\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{k+n}),\; \Phi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{k+n},\mathbb{R}),\; x\in \mathbb{R}^k.
$$
This way, we get for each $\lambda$ a function $I_\lambda\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{k})$. Consider now an oscillatory integral of the second kind
$$
I_2(x)=\intop_{\mathbb{R}^l}e^{i\phi(x,\xi)}b(x,\xi)\,d \xi,\qquad x\in \mathbb{R}^k,\quad b\in S^m(\mathbb{R}^{k+l}),\quad \phi:\mathbb{R}^{k+l}\to \mathbb{R},
$$
where $\phi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k\times\mathbb{R}^l\backslash \{0\})$ is  a phase function and $S^m(\mathbb{R}^{k+l})$ is a symbol class.

While $I_\lambda(x)$ is an absolutely convergent integral and strong oscillations only take place in the limit $\lambda \to \infty$, the "integral" $I_2$ is technically a distribution, defined by
$$
<I_2,u>:=\lim_{R\to \infty}\intop_{\mathbb{R}^l}\intop_{\mathbb{R}^k}e^{i\phi(x,\xi)}b(x,\xi)\chi(\xi/R)u(x)\,d x\,d \xi,\qquad u\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^k),
$$
where $\chi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^l)$ is identically $1$ in some open ball around the origin. (Alternatively, one can use an exponentially decaying function).

Now, we can consider the application of $I_2$ to $I_\lambda$
$$
\widetilde I(\lambda):=<I_2,I_\lambda>\equiv\lim_{R\to \infty}\intop_{\mathbb{R}^l}\intop_{\mathbb{R}^k}e^{i\phi(x,\xi)}b(x,\xi)\chi(\xi/R)\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e^{i\lambda\Phi(x,y)}a(x,y)\,d y\,d x\,d \xi
$$
as well as the generalization
$$
I(\lambda):=<I_2,I_\lambda>\equiv\lim_{R\to \infty}\intop_{\mathbb{R}^l}\intop_{\mathbb{R}^k}e^{i\phi(x,\xi)}b_\lambda(x,\xi)\chi(\xi/R)\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e^{i\lambda\Phi(x,y)}a(x,y)\,d y\,d x\,d \xi\\
=\lim_{R\to \infty}\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{l+k+n}}e^{i[\phi(x,\xi)+\lambda\Phi(x,y)]}b_\lambda(x,\xi)\chi(\xi/R)a(x,y)\,d y\,d x\,d \xi
$$
where the symbol function is allowed to vary with $\lambda$. The problem is now to study the behaviour of $I(\lambda)$ in the limit $\lambda\to \infty$.

**Has anyone systematically studied such limits before?**

**Is there a reference where combinations of oscillatory integrals of both types are treated (even implicitly)?**

Comment: Could you just do it one step at a time? I guess the asymptotics of $\lambda\to\infty$ is not much different from that of the first kind.